# Bearer token as variable in curl

Tags: curl

I'm trying to pass variable for bearer token, I fail do forge my request.
Basically if I add the token manually it works.

```
curl ... --header "Authorization: Bearer MmM2MDZkMDA0MjE0" --verbose
* About to connect()
* Connected to ...
* ...
> Authorization: Bearer MmM2MDZkMDA0MjE0
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<...
    response header and body was here
...
* Connection #0 to host host.local left intact
```

But when I try to assign it to a variable, it's not working

```
$bearerToken='MmM2MDZkMDA0MjE0'
curl ... --header "Authorization: Bearer $bearerToken" --verbose
* About to connect()
* Connected to ...
* ...
> Authorization: Bearer MmM2MDZkMDA0MjE0
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad EOL
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
```

I even try with creating variable like the one bellow and pass it, but I had the same output

```
testToken='Authorization: Bearer '$bearerToken
curl ... --header $testToken
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I found is that curl is broken because when using variables they include new line at the end. What worked for me is using:

`"Authorization: Bearer ${bearerToken//[$'\t\r\n ']}"`